# check if a username appears in the output of who

Tags: linux, bash

The task requires that a bash script be written that will search the "who" command for a given user ID which will be provided via command line argument

This script will display whether or not this user ID is logged in

So far I know that to get the user ID, one can do:

```
who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "userIdToSearchFor"
```

This grep will display the user ID if it exists, or nothing if it doesn't, so it seems like a good method

I believe the `$1` variable will hold the first command line argument

How can I implement this in a bash script file please?

EDIT:

Current working script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
userid=$(who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "$1") 

if [ "$1" == "$userid" ]
then
   echo    "online" 
else    
   echo    "offline" 
fi
```

Comment: put this: `who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "$1"` in a file named `script.bash`, give permissions to execute using `chmod 755 script.bash` and then run `./script.bash "userIdToSearchFor"`

Comment: Ah ok thank you, may I ask, how would this be implemented in a #!/bin/bash  file please?

Comment: LOL. Are we currently doing your homework, or something? :)

Comment: Afraid so, got a lot alone done but having trouble with last couple ones, sorry hehe

Comment: Thank you again, I put the current script in the main post, I am unsure why it gives: line 2 STRING: command not found

Comment: Remove spaces in the var assignment `̀STRING=$(who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "$1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
STRING=$(who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "$1")

if [ "$1" = "$STRING" ]
then
   echo    "online" 
else    
   echo    "offline"
fi
```

Some comments and suggestions :

- No spaces on both sides of the `=` when you assign variables (that's where your error message come from).
- To assign commands result to a variable, you must use the `$( )` syntax. See [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) for more.
- Quote you vars in your test to prevent word splitting.
- You should loop on the test, there could be multiple identical usernames.
- Avoid caps in you variable names not to confuse with [environment variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) which are capitalized by convention.
- Avoid to use the type of the var for its name, in your case `username` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the hard way.

```
$ cat user.sh
#!/bin/bash
# user.sh username - shows whether username is logged on or not

if who | grep --silent "^$1 " ; then
   echo online
else
   echo offline
fi
$ ./user.sh msw
online
```